# FreePBX with Twilio SIP trunk incoming call dosen’t hit the freepbx server

Tags: twilio, sip, pjsip, freepbx

I am using FreePBX version 16 and configured SIP trunk with Twilio.
I refered the following doc
https://assets.cdn.prod.twilio.com/documents/TwilioElasticSIPTrunking-FreePBX-Configuration-Guide-Version1-0-FINAL-06122018.pdf

The Phone to test calls is done using webrtc phone provided by FreePBX UCP.
I can make outbound calls through this trunk but not able to make inbound calls.

I am attaching log of twilio call log error for incoming call fail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njbAU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TEbk.png)
The freepbx firewall servers are all disabled.

Checked if the firewall is blocking twilio signalling ip's which isn't. Checked the origination url no luck. The issue is that the communication signal from twilio sip trunk to freePBX isn't established thereby failing incoming calls to freePBX.

Comment: If you check the log for the call, you should be able to view the IP address that the call attempted to reach. This might give you some insights. You might also be able to download the SIP PCAP file which you can view for more insights.